# Character pointer passed as parameter converting to string

Tags: c++, regex, visual-c++

Hi I am new to C++ and I require some input for the following problem:

In my header file (MyClass.h) a function is defined as:

```
bool Function(char *InString,char *outStr);
```

This has been implemented in "MyClass.cpp" like this:

```
bool MyClass::Function(char *InString,char *OutString=0) {
  std::string str = ***** I require the InString to be converted to String and assigned to str.
}
```

In my main function of console I used the following function:

```
#include "MyClass.h"
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[]) {
  char inp[50];
  char output[50];
  memset(output,0,sizeof(output));//Intialized
  std::cin>>inp;
  MyClass x;
  bool m = x.Function(inp,output);
}
```

Any help is deeply appreciated.

Comment: I suggest you start reading some basic tutorials, as this is something very simple and basic.

Comment: Why aren't you using `std::string` universally throughout your program?

Comment: Also, default parameters go in declarations, not definitions.

Comment: @VittorioRomeo Unless the definition also *is* the declaration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well `std::string` has a constructor for this:

```
const char *s = "\nHello, World!";
std::string str(s);
cout<<str;

char *s2 = "\nHello, World!";
std::string str2(s2);
cout<<str2;
```

gives me:

> Hello, World!
>
> Hello, World!

Answer (score 1):

By

```
str.assign(InString);
```

you can assign a `char` to a `std::string`.

Answer (score 1):

You can just assingn the character pointer to the string.  As long as the data pointed to by the character pointer is null terminated, the copy will work as expected.

```
std::string str = InString;
```

Comment: OKay i got your point. I am studying null pointer in detail. I suppose after using memset we initialize and character array with 0 which automatically puts null pointer.

Answer (score 0):

Just `std::string str = InString;` should work.